# Group x entity in undefined number of groups with z grouping constraints using OptaPlanner

Tags: algorithm, optaplanner

I'm trying to modelize a problem using OptaPlanner, but I can't find a modeling. (I'm starting with OptaPlanner).

My problem is the following :

- I have x numbers of objet named `Process` as input
- I want to group `Process` in undefined numbers (we will name it y) of
  `Group`.
- I have z criterias for grouping as input

I want to have a minimum number of `Group` with a maximum number of `Process` in each 
`Group` and all `Process` of the same `Group` are compatible (by criterias).

Below some examples of criterias :

- `Process` have field `name`, the constraint can be `Process must have name starting with 'a'`
- `Process` have field `code`, the constraint can be `Process must have same code`
- `Process` have field `dateMin` and `dateMax`, the constraint can be `dateMin and dateMax overlap between Process`

Example :
I have 5 `Process`

- P1 (name = "ab", code = 1)
- P2 (name = "ac", code = 2)
- P3 (name = "ad", code = 1)
- P4 (name = "ba", code = 1)
- P5 (name = "ca", code = 3)

I want to calculate a score for the following combination using the example criterias above
(P1,P2,P3), (P1,P3,P4), (P5). 
All others combinations should be excluded as incompatible

Is there any way to do this using OptaPlanner. Which approach should i study in order to try to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds similar to the CloudBalancing problem mostly.
Take that example, rename `Computer` to `Group` (and `Process` remains `Process`).

Then you can do constraint streams like

```
// Process have field code, the constraint can be Process must have same code
from(Process)
.groupBy(Process::getComputer, countDistinct(Process::getCode)
.filter((computer, codeCount) -> codeCount > 1)
.penalize(...);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will try it immediately. I'm agree that it sounds like CloudBalancing problem. But in the CloudBalancing we have a defined number of Computer, in my problem i didn't have a defined number of Group (computer). Watching GroupBalancing problem, i think i can predefine a large numbers of group as input (1000 for example) and reduce the solution score (like the cost in CloudBalancing). Is there any better way to achieve this ?

Comment: Finally, i generated same numbers of group as process and i implemented a soft constraint to prefer more grouped process, i used hard constraint for my grouping criteria. Due to project time due, i used an easy score calculator. Thanks a lot for your help